# Can i use two actions on an else statement?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if it's a basic question but i can't make two "actions" work on one single else if.

I want it to say different greetings and at the same time change the background color of body based on the present hour.

The code works without this line:

```
document.getElementById("####").style.background = '#######';
```

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
    var today = new Date();
    var hourNow = today.getHours();
    var greeting;

    if (hourNow > 20) {
        greeting = 'Boa noite!'; document.getElementById("body").style.background = '#000000';
    } else if (hourNow > 12) {
        greeting = 'Boa tarde!';
        document.getElementById("body").style.background = '#ffffff'; 
    } else if (hourNow > 0) {
        greeting = 'Bom descanço!'; document.getElementById("body").style.background = '#121212';
    } else if (hourNow > 7) {
        greeting = 'Bom dia!'; document.getElementById("body").style.background = '#bf3d3d';
    }
    document.write(greeting);
```

I appreciate every help i can get! Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. What's not working? Also, `document.write()` is archaic and should be avoided. Look into DOM scripting instead.

Comment: try using document.body.style.backgroundColor ="######"; instea, also do this the same way as your greetings to save on the amount of code

Comment: Do you have an element with id `body` in your HTML ? Just open the dev console and check if you do see any errors.

Comment: Seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/3hLggq5g/

Comment: When i add the line "document.getElementById("body").style.background = '#000000'; the code stops working. 
Thank you so much for the advice i will take a look into that!

Comment: Thanks @krisph i will try that!

Comment: @Sushanth i do have an body element on my HTML. Theres no errors showing on my dev console.

Comment: @08691 Thank you, i will try to see what's happening on my end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for the wanted parameters to change and use an array of the keys in the wanted order with a callback for changing the given values.

```js
var greetings = {
        20: {
            greeting: 'Boa noite!',
            background: '#000000'
        },
        12: {
            greeting: 'Boa tarde!',
            background: '#ffffff'
        },
        7: {
            greeting: 'Bom dia!',
            background:'#bf3d3d'
        },
        0: {
            greeting: 'Bom descanço!',
            background: '#121212'
        }
    },
    hourNow = (new Date).getHours();


[20, 12, 7, 0].some(function (hour) {
    if (hourNow >= hour) { // check for greater and equal
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = greetings[hour].greeting; 
        document.body.style.background = greetings[hour].background;
        return true;       // exit loop
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="greeting" style="background-color: #ffffff;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `<h1>` tag to your body and then set the innerText on that for the greeting.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<h1 id="greeting"></h1>

// JS
var greeting = document.getElementById('greeting');

if (hourNow > 20) {
    greeting.innerText = 'Boa noite!';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that way is much better!
Javascript is a very recent thing to me, thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should put

```
else if (hourNow > 7)
```

before

```
else if (hourNow > 0)
```

Right now the last else if is unreachable

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and leverage the fall-through behavior when you do not supply a `break` in a `case`.